# Celery: Redis as broker leaving task meta keys

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have celery app with Redis as broker.

The code consist of the following in a loop :

```
running = []
res = add.apply_async([1,2], queue='add')
running.append(res)

while running:
    r = running.pop()
    if r.ready():
        print r.get()
    else:
        running.insert(0,r)
```

everything works fine but when i `redis-cli` into redis and execute `keys *`
I see bunch of celery-task-meta keys.

Why arent they cleaned up?
What are those for?

--

[EDIT]

I've read about CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES setting.
Is it possible for the task keys in Redis to be cleaned up right after the result is read rather than wait until the expiration time?

Comment: Do you know the task_id or do you have the AsyncResult of your job? If so you can AsyncResult.forget(). From the docs: Forget about (and possibly remove the result of) this task.

Comment: yes i do have AsyncResult (its the variable 'r'). so would i have to r.get() and r.forget() right afterwards?

Comment: please give it a shot, becuase I have not tried myself. I was looking into it because I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

From the Celery Doc:

```
AsyncResult.forget()
   Forget about (and possibly remove the result of) this task.
```

You have to first `r.get()` then `r.forget()`

But, You needn't cleaned up the keys.
For,[doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires) say that:

CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES

Default is to expire after 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. What fixed it for me was adding `app.autodiscover_tasks()` to my celery.py file

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to ignore the result completely which can be done by setting this flag, 'task_ignore_result' as True. This doesn't store the result at all.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-ignore-result